# Oracle cannot connect to SQL developer as sys account

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I am trying to connect to SQL developer as sys account.  It is always giving the error `invalid username/password`. When I try to connect it through SQLPLUS, it gets connect with any wrong password also.

How can I connect to SQL Developer using sys account?

Answer (score 1):

`sqlplus user/password as sysdba` uses OS authentication by default, and bypasses the username and password check, so as you said, you can provide any password or username.

Logging in from SQL Developer requires a remote session. For a remote SYSDBA connection, you need the following:

1. set `remote_login_passwordfile` to `EXCLUSIVE` or `SHARED`, but not `NONE`
2. create a password file for the database if it doesn't already exist:

`$ orapwd file=$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapw$ORACLE_SID`

After this you should be able to log in with SYS and the password you provided.

Comment: I tried creating orapwd file but not working

Answer (score 0):

Log in to SQL*Plus using *sys* and change the password for *sys*. Then try logging in SQL Developer, it will work.

```
Alter user sys identified by new_password;
```